# Unable to destroy and recreate kendo ui grid using destroy method

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am receiving an error when i try to destroy a kendo grid.. here is the error.

```
Unhandled exception at line 18, column 8575 in http://localhost:21909/Content/Kendo/kendo.all.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'destroy' of undefined or null   reference
```

I just cant figure out what's wrong with my code. the javascript is like this

```
getContactGrid: function (categorytx) {
        var self = this;
        self.kgrid.destroy();
        self.kgrid.wrapper.empty();
        $.get(GetAppPath() + 'Grid/GetGrid?gridid=contact_kgrid&gridParams=viewty=' + categorytx + ';', function (datatx) {
            $("#grid-container").empty();
            $("#grid-container").append(datatx);
        }).fail(function () {
            $('#msg-div').Message({ resourcecd: 'ERR_OCCURED', delayno: 6000 });
        }).complete(function (datatx) {
            self.appendFilter(categorytx);
            $('#master_div div[data-gridyn=true]').Kgrid();
            self.viewHistory();
        });
    },
```

i am getting grid as a partial view but destroy method throws the said exception

Comment: What it is saying is that `kgrid` is undefined or `null`. Did you check that ´kgrid` has a valid value while executing `getContactGrid` code?

Comment: yes sir @OnaBai it has a value. this point me out in the main script in kendo scripts.